# datagridview combobox cell c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

My code:

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();     
 DataTable data = new DataTable();

data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));



data.Rows.Add("5", "6");
data.Rows.Add("51", "26");
data.Rows.Add("531", "63");
cell.DataSource = data;
cell.ValueMember = "Value";
cell.DisplayMember = "Description";

cell.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = cell;
```

It displays combobox but can't select  any value of it. 
Whats wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You generally don't work with the individual cell types in the `DataGridView`. Instead you want to add a column of type `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

So instead of your provided code you want something like:

```
var column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();      
DataTable data = new DataTable(); 

data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string))); 
data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string))); 

data.Rows.Add("5", "6"); 
data.Rows.Add("51", "26"); 
data.Rows.Add("531", "63"); 

column.DataSource = data; 
column.ValueMember = "Value"; 
column.DisplayMember = "Description"; 

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

For reference, the documentation on the DataGridViewCombobBoxCell is on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx). You can also find information on the DataGridView in general there. Another very good reference is the [DataGridViewFAQ](http://www.windowsclient.net/Samples/Go%20To%20Market/DataGridView/DataGridView%20FAQ.doc).

Comment: I don't know why, but using this code (for a nullable item) does NOT show the selected value, but does shows the list of item on the dropped box.