# Datagridview box combo box

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview combo box column with Read Only property set to False.
I need to insert values to the combo box (say One, Two, Three etc.) and also I need the combo box to display a certian value stored in a variable (say dim abc as string="value")

I need the combo box to display value stored in abc when the form loads.

Please advise how to achieve these two tasks.

Thanks

Comment: c# but could help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533067/datagridview-combobox-cell-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combobox-type `DataGridView` cells/columns are, by default, `read-only` (users cannot change their items). Sample code to start a `DataGridView1` with a combobox-type column, populated with the values you wish:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim curCol As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

    Dim abc As String = "value"
    Dim items As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    items.Add("One")
    items.Add("Two")
    items.Add("Three")
    items.Add(abc)

    curCol.DataSource = items

    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(curCol)

End Sub
```